# ExecuteReaderAsync task hangs / continuously WaitingForActivation

Tags: .net

I have the following procedure that seems straightforward but just waits continuously without timing out:

```
Public Overrides Async Function ExecuteReaderAsync() As Task(Of Boolean)
    If Not IsNothing(Command) Then 'Command is a the standard SqlCommand object
        If Not IsNothing(Command.Connection) Then
            Try
                ExecutionFailed = True
                Command.Connection.Open()
                Reader = Await Command.ExecuteReaderAsync
                IsExecuted = True
                ExecutionFailed = False
                Return True
            Catch ex As Exception
                Debugger.Break()
            End Try
        End If
    End If

    Return False
End Function
```

The above code executes the Reader = Await Command.ExecuteReaderAsync line and just hangs there.

If I replace that line with these:

```
Dim t = Command.ExecuteReaderAsync
Reader = Await t
```

and break at the await, I can see task t has a status of WaitingForActivation. I can also see on the SQL Profiler that the SP the reader is calling has been executed correctly.

Now for the weird part - if I add a thread.sleep for 10ms and then look at t, the task has RunToCompletion as its status and all is well in the world.

```
Dim t = Command.ExecuteReaderAsync
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
Reader = Await t
```

I'm quite willing to accept I am doing something wrong (it's normally the case...) but I have no idea what in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is to do with contexts and my code was causing a deadlock. This page was enormously helpful to me and provides a full explanation on why the deadlocks occur:

[Don't Block on Async Code - Stephen Cleary](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

The solution is to apply ConfigureAwait to a Task in the following way:

```
Await Command.Connection.OpenAsync.ConfigureAwait(False)
Reader = Await Command.ExecuteReaderAsync.ConfigureAwait(False)
```

I was migrating from MySql to SQL Server - MySql async commands don't seem to exhibit the same problem and have no need for ConfigureAwait.

Comment: I bet the MySQL commands don't exhibit this problem because they aren't *actually* asynchronous. I've seen that plenty of times - just doing the equivalent of `return Task.FromResult(ExecuteReader());`. Also note that it's possible for tasks to return synchronously *if* they are finished before they are returned. I've seen this happen with e.g. `HttpClient.GetAsync`, and it happens quite often with streamed I/O.

Comment: Thanks for that link. Instead of using ConfigureAwait(false) everywhere, you can potentially refactor your code to do async all the way down as mentioned in that link - will fix the problem, without copy pasting that code everywhere. Of course you may need to refactor a lot of code so might not be possible in all cases.

Comment: You're ability to be completely async depends on what you are coding - old fashioned WebApi or Console projects can't be async (I know that c# supports this now, but haven't seen vb.net support released yet).